# WebPack replace vendor require call with global variable

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, commonjs

Having trouble with WebPack. I have a vendor library (saying `ChildVendor`), which implements requireJS and commonJS compatibility, so, I need to require it in my WebPack project like `var lib = require('./childVendor');`. This `ChildVendor` library has a dependency (saying `SuperVendor`), and both of them are requirejs- and commonjs-adapted, so, the heading of `childVendor.js` looks like:

```
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(["superVendor"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('superVendor'));
  } else {
    root.Shepherd = factory(root.SuperVendor);
  }
}(this, function(SuperVendor) { /*...*/ }));
```

The main problem is that I need to include that `SuperVendor` library globally on html-file manually (so, it is just initialized as window.SuperVendor), because it should be used by other third-party libraries.

To solve this, I have tried `webpack.ProvidePlugin`, like

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'superVendor': 'SuperVendor'
    })
],
```

but an error is still the same (`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'superVendor' in '...'`).

Answer (score 0):

`ProvidePlugin` is not the solution for what you want to do. The configuration you've set with it tells Webpack:

> Whenever `superVendor` is encountered as a free variable in a module, load the module `SuperVendor` and set the variable `superVendor` to what exported by `SuperVendor`.

In other words if you have a module that contains this:

```
superVendor.someMethod();
```

Webpack interprets it as if it were:

```
var superVendor = require("SuperVendor");
superVendor.someMethod();
```

What you should use it the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) configuration option:

```
externals: {
  'superVendor': 'SuperVendor'
}
```

This tells Webpack that if the module `superVendor` is required it should be sought from the external environment with the name `SuperVendor`.